# Salesforce reports access using oauth as session id

Tags: web-services, oauth, report, salesforce, force.com

I'm trying to get access to salesforce report data using oauth token. Some time ago it worked fine, I used the oauth token as session id.

```
...
URL remoteFile = new URL(instanceURL + "/" + reportId + "?export=1&enc=UTF-8&xf=csv");
URLConnection fStream = remoteFile.openConnection();
fStream.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "sid=" + accessToken);
...
```

But it doesn't work, everytime I try to access the url it returns an html page which corresponds to login page. Is there any way I can access report data (not meta-data) using the oauth access_token?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it just a matter of an expired token?

Comment: No, I can make request to other apis, but the url I'm calling is a url that would be called from a web browser, documentation says that access token might be used instead of the session id, but it doesn't work for that particular purpose in this case.

Comment: Ah I see, I believe there are two types of token you can request, one is called a full access token or similar which can then be used to generate such a URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use the token with such a URL you need to [set the scope parameter to include `web`](https://ap1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/remoteaccess_oauth_scopes.htm):

> web   Allows the ability to use the access_token on the Web.

[The oAuth User Agent Flow documentation](https://ap1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/remoteaccess_oauth_user_agent_flow.htm) details where the `scope` parameter is specified.

Comment: Thank you, your answer was very helpful, actually my code contained some errors that I wasn't able to see.